# Ef Core initial migration adds prefixed columns in TPH conf for same name properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In a TPH mapping and a discriminator column present Ef Core still creates prefixed columns for properties that have same name in derived classes. I was under the impression that properties with the same name, type and nullability will map to same column in db per default when using TPH mapping.

So I've created most simple console app project, using .net7 and latest 7.0.14 (tested later with .net8 with same outcome though)

Base Class:

```
public abstract  class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

First Derived class:

```
public  class Derived1 : BaseClass
{
    public bool BoolFlagBla { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Second Derived Class:

```
public class Derived2 : BaseClass
{
    public int D1RandomProp { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class BBContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)    
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .LogTo(str => Console.WriteLine(str));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().UseTphMappingStrategy();
    }


    public DbSet<Derived1> DerivedSet1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Derived2> DerivedSet2 { get; set; }
}
```

and finally a migration created by "add-migration init" command in PM console:

```
#nullable disable

namespace TestTPH.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class init : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "BaseClass",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false).Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    Discriminator = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    BoolFlagBla = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: true),
                    ProjectNumber= table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    D1RandomProp = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                   Derived2_ProjectNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_BaseClass", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "BaseClass");
        }
    }
}
```

*observe ProjectNumber and Derived2_ProjectNumber*
Normally, EF Core should create only one column for ProjectNumber since it's common to both Derived1 and Derived2. However, it's generating an additional column Derived2_ProjectNumber, which is not the expected behavior.
I'd like to avoid using .HasColumnName on each such property and entity as I have quite many of derived entities that have same named properties
Can someone shed some light on this problem ?

Comment: İf those properties are common they should be on the baseclass not on the derived ones

Comment: Yes, agree, see my comment on the Bogdans answer to see why i cannot do that

Answer (score 1):

There's an obvious solution for the described issue: just put the `ProjectNumber` property higher in the entity-class hierarchy. It looks like You are unable to put this property in the `BaseClass` (for some reason), but it doesn't mean, that You can't put it somewhere else.

You can introduce an intermediate abstract entity-class to represent the concept of the duplicate `ProjectNumber` property. If You do this, the resulting entities will look somewhat like this:

Base Class:

```cs
public abstract  class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Intermediate entity for shared properties:

```cs
public abstract class Project : BaseClass
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

First Derived class:

```cs
public  class Derived1 : Project 
{
    public bool BoolFlagBla { get; set; }
}
```

Second Derived Class:

```cs
public class Derived2 : Project 
{
    public int D1RandomProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The reason that I cannot do that is that i have about 100 entities derived from the base class in the real project and only some of these have ProjectNumber property.  

Many of my entities have same name properties other than ProjectNumber,

In my question I scaled down to this test project only to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I was under the wrong impression that default behavior was to map properties with same name to same DB column

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#shared-columns

states quite the opposite, which is strange to me.

So my workaround, because of the number of my entities and different same named props is a turn to reflection

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentBase>().UseTphMappingStrategy()
            .Property(cb => cb.Hours)
            .HasPrecision(9,2);

        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ComponentBase));

        var types = assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ComponentBase)))
            .ToList();

        var baseProps = typeof(ComponentBase).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

        foreach(Type type in types)
        {
            var props = type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Where(p => !baseProps.Contains(p)).ToList();

            props.ForEach(p =>
            {                
                modelBuilder.Entity(type).Property(p).HasColumnName(p);
            });             
        }        
    }
```

extracting all sub types , getting property names, subtracting base class properties and finally using HasColumnName  produces clean migration with no prefixed column names.